# HTML Form, send Information from User to Email Server (Outlook) with an file attatchment

Tags: php, html, forms, email, outlook

Website problem: [http://mike-kaufmann.de/contact.html][1]

Hello,

i want that a user on my Website is able to upload a file on my Server and i get that as an Email.

The normal Text Input works. -No problem there

Ive created a button where the User can upload files. I can successfully send the Email, but i dont get it into my Email account.

Before i started to create the File attachment, the normal Input text´s worked, i got an email with the Information etc.

Now i get no email.

Question/s:

Is it able to get a Email with the Information input from a Form with a file attachment that i can download from my email client.

My current code:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Mike Kaufmann - Homepage | Contact</title>

        <!-- WEBSITE META CODE NAMES -->
        <meta name="description" content="Meine offizielle Seite"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Mike Kaufmann, Mike Buymann, Website, Portfolio, FAQ, Design"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Mike Kaufmann"/>
        <meta name="Copyright" content="Mike Kaufmann" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"> <!--Erzwingt IE7+spätere Versionen, darzustellen-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <!-- END -->

        <!-- WEB STYLE -->
        <link href="style/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="fonts/fonts.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
        <link href="js/onClickalert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- END -->
</head>
```

```
<script>
    function emailFunction() {
        var emailadress = prompt("Email-adress:", "kaufmann.mike@live.de");
    }

    function skypeFunction() {
        var skypename = prompt("Skype-name:", "bobbybie");
    }
</script>

<header>
    <div id="header_nav_bar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
                    <svg>
                        <a xlink:href="index.html"> 
                            <path fill="#313131" d="M29.5,0C13.2,0,0,13.3,0,29.5S13.2,59,29.5,59S59,45.8,59,
                            29.5S45.8,0,29.5,0z M33,40.8l-6-5.7v-5l-3.1,3.1l-3.3-3l0,8.2L14.9,44l0-21.7l12.4,0.1L33,28V40.8z            
                            M43,29.5l0,7.5L27.2,21.3l0-6.4l5.7,0l-0.1,3.7l3.8-3.7l6.9,0L36,22.5L43,29.5z"/></a>
                    </svg>
                <li><a href="aboutme.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header> 

<div class="content">
    <div id="contact_form">
        <div id="saghallobox">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="contactHTMLform.php" method="POST">
                <div class="fade-in.three">
                    <legend>SAY HI!</legend>
                </div>
                    <li1><p><input name="name" type="text" required id="name" placeholder="Name"></p></li1>
                    <li2><p><input name="email" type="text" required id="email" placeholder="Email"/></p></li2>
                    <p><textarea name="message" required id="nachricht" placeholder="Message"/></textarea></p>
                    <input type="file" name="filea" id="fileToUpload" style="width:111px;">
                    <button name="submit" type="Submit" value="Send File"><p>Send</p></button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- END Contact form -->

    <div id="mobile_number">
        <div id="mobile_icon">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <g>
                <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#313131" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#313131" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#313131" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
            </g>
            <path fill="#FAFAFA" d="M39.5,51.6c-0.7-0.1-1.5-0.2-2.3-0.5c-4.4-1.3-8.2-3.6-11.5-6.9c-3.2-3.2-5.4-6.9-6.8-11.2
                c-0.9-2.8-0.3-5.2,1.3-7.5c1-1.5,2.6-1.8,4.3-1.9c0.3,0,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.6c1.1,1.8,2.1,3.7,3.2,5.5c0.3,0.6,0.2,1.1-0.3,1.5
                c-0.7,0.7-1.5,1.3-2.2,2c-1,0.9-1.1,1.3-0.4,2.5c2.1,3.9,5.1,6.8,9,8.9c1.1,0.6,1.4,0.6,2.2-0.3c0.7-0.7,1.2-1.5,1.9-2.2
                c0.8-0.8,1.2-0.8,2.1-0.3c1.6,0.9,3.2,1.9,4.8,2.7c0.8,0.4,1,1.1,0.9,1.9c-0.5,2.7-2.1,4.2-5.3,4.9C40.6,51.4,40.1,51.5,39.5,51.6z"
                />
            </svg>
        </div>
            <h3><code>Mobile:</code></h3>
            <p><code>+49 0176 825 04 706</code></p>
    </div>

    <div id="street">
        <div id="street_icon">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <g>
                    <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#313131" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#313131" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#313131" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <path fill="#FAFAFA" d="M35.3,51.6c0-2.8,0-5.6,0-8.3c-1.9,0-3.7,0-5.6,0c0,2.7,0,5.5,0,8.3c-0.3,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1
                        c-2.5,0-5,0-7.5,0c-1.2,0-1.7-0.5-1.7-1.7c0-3.3,0-6.5,0-9.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.7c4.1-3.4,8.1-6.7,12.3-10.1
                        c0.9,0.7,1.7,1.4,2.5,2.1c3.2,2.6,6.4,5.3,9.6,7.9c0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.5,1c0,3.2,0,6.3,0,9.5c0,1.4-0.5,1.9-1.9,1.9
                        C40.6,51.6,38,51.6,35.3,51.6z"/>
                    <path fill="#FAFAFA" d="M39.5,28.6c0-1.4,0-2.7,0-3.9c0-0.8,0.2-1,1-1c1.2,0,2.4,0,3.6,0c0.8,0,1,0.2,1,1c0,2.7,0,5.3,0,8
                        c0,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.5,1c1.4,1.1,2.7,2.2,4.1,3.4c0.6,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.1,1.4c-0.3,0.4-0.6,0.7-0.9,1.1c-0.5,0.6-0.8,0.6-1.5,0.1
                        c-2.8-2.3-5.6-4.6-8.4-7c-2-1.7-4-3.3-5.9-5c-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.3-1,0c-4.7,4-9.5,7.9-14.3,11.9c-0.7,0.6-1,0.6-1.6-0.1
                        c-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.7-0.9-1c-0.5-0.6-0.5-0.9,0.1-1.4c2.1-1.8,4.2-3.5,6.3-5.2c3-2.5,5.9-4.9,8.9-7.4c1.3-1.1,2.6-1.1,3.9,0
                        c1.5,1.3,3.1,2.6,4.6,3.8C39.1,28.3,39.3,28.4,39.5,28.6z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
            <h3><code>Street:</code></h3>
            <p><code>Eschenweg 6 33330</code></p>
            <p><code>Gütersloh</code></p>
    </div>

    <div id="social_media">
        <div id="hexagon1_contact">
        <div id="facebook_icon">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <a xlink:href="https://www.facebook.com/mkmikekaufmann" target="_blank">
                <g id="hexagon">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#3A5695" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#3A5695" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#3A5695" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="FB-Icon">
                    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M32.5,56.4l-4.7-2.8c0,0,0-10.7,0-16.1c-1.3,0-2.6,0-3.9,0c0-2.2,0-4.3,0-6.5c1.3,0,2.6,0,3.9,0
                        c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6c0-1.9,0-3.7,0.1-5.6c0.1-2.1,1-3.9,3-5c1.4-0.8,2.9-1,4.4-1.1c1.9,0,3.8,0,5.7,0c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0
                        c0,2.2,0,4.3,0,6.5c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0c-1.2,0-2.4,0-3.6,0c-1.3,0-1.7,0.5-1.7,1.7c0,1.3,0,2.6,0,4c2,0,3.9,0,5.8,0
                        c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.4-0.2,2.1c-0.1,1.3-0.2,2.6-0.3,4c0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.4c-1.4,0-2.9,0-4.3,0c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0
                        c0,5.8,0,17.3,0,17.3L32.5,56.4z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hexagon2_contact">
        <div id="youtube_icon">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <a xlink:href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdeXtTROfjO_9ZtAtga9nBA" target="_blank">
                <g id="hexagon">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#CD201F" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#CD201F" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#CD201F" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="youtube-icon">
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <polyline fill="#E8E7E8" points="37.3,37.8 28.8,32.1 38.5,37.2 37.3,37.8            "/>
                            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M28.8,42.2l0-10.1l9.7,5.1L28.8,42.2L28.8,42.2z M50.1,30.4c0,0-0.4-2.5-1.4-3.6
                                c-1.4-1.4-2.9-1.4-3.6-1.5c-5-0.4-12.6-0.4-12.6-0.4h0c0,0-7.6,0-12.6,0.4c-0.7,0.1-2.2,0.1-3.6,1.5c-1.1,1.1-1.4,3.6-1.4,3.6
                                s-0.4,2.9-0.4,5.8v2.7c0,2.9,0.4,5.8,0.4,5.8s0.4,2.5,1.4,3.6c1.4,1.4,3.2,1.4,4,1.5c2.9,0.3,12.2,0.4,12.2,0.4s7.6,0,12.6-0.4
                                c0.7-0.1,2.2-0.1,3.6-1.5c1.1-1.1,1.4-3.6,1.4-3.6s0.4-2.9,0.4-5.8v-2.7C50.5,33.3,50.1,30.4,50.1,30.4L50.1,30.4z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hexagon3_contact">
        <div id="twitter_icon">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <a xlink:href="https://twitter.com/mkmike000" target="_blank">
                <g id="hexagon">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#55ACEE" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#55ACEE" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#55ACEE" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="twitter-icon">
                    <g>
                        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M47.3,28.4c-1.1,0.5-2.3,0.8-3.6,1c1.3-0.8,2.3-2,2.7-3.4c-1.2,0.7-2.5,1.2-3.9,1.5c-1.1-1.2-2.7-2-4.5-2
                            c-3.4,0-6.2,2.8-6.2,6.2c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.4c-5.2-0.3-9.7-2.7-12.8-6.5c-0.5,0.9-0.8,2-0.8,3.1c0,2.2,1.1,4.1,2.8,5.2
                            c-1,0-2-0.3-2.8-0.8c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,3,2.1,5.5,5,6.1c-0.5,0.1-1.1,0.2-1.6,0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.2-0.1c0.8,2.5,3.1,4.3,5.8,4.3
                            c-2.1,1.7-4.8,2.7-7.7,2.7c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5-0.1c2.7,1.8,6,2.8,9.5,2.8c11.4,0,17.6-9.5,17.6-17.6c0-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8
                            C45.5,30.8,46.5,29.7,47.3,28.4L47.3,28.4z"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hexagon4_contact">
        <div id="behance_icon">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <a xlink:href="https://www.behance.net/MikeMK" target="_blank">
                <g id="hexagon">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#2B2B2B" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#2B2B2B" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#2B2B2B" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="behance-icon">
                    <g>
                        <path fill="#FAFAFA" d="M17.3,46.8c0-6.3,0-12.6,0-18.9c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c3.1,0,6.2,0,9.4,0c1.3,0,2.5,0.3,3.5,1
                            c1.4,1,1.9,2.5,1.8,4.2c-0.1,1.6-0.8,2.7-2.2,3.4c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1c2,0.8,2.8,2.7,2.7,4.7c-0.2,3-2.2,5-5.3,5.3
                            c-0.6,0.1-1.3,0.1-1.9,0.1c-2.6,0-5.2,0-7.8,0C17.6,46.8,17.4,46.8,17.3,46.8z M21.1,43.4c1.8,0,3.6,0.1,5.4,0
                            c1.3-0.1,2-0.8,2.2-1.9c0.1-0.4,0.1-0.7,0-1.1c-0.1-0.8-0.5-1.3-1.2-1.6c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.3-1.3-0.3c-1.7,0-3.3,0-5,0
                            c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0C21.1,40.1,21.1,41.8,21.1,43.4z M21.1,31.2c0,1.4,0,2.8,0,4.1c1.7,0,3.3,0.1,5,0c1.7-0.1,2.4-0.9,2.3-2.4
                            c-0.1-0.8-0.5-1.3-1.2-1.5c-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.5-0.2C24.1,31.2,22.6,31.2,21.1,31.2z"/>
                        <path fill="#FAFAFA" d="M37.5,40.8c0,2,1.2,3.4,3.1,3.4c1.3,0.1,2.3-0.3,3-1.4c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.2c1.2,0,2.4,0,3.7,0
                            c-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.2c-0.7,1.3-1.7,2.3-3.1,2.8c-2.5,0.9-4.9,0.8-7.2-0.6c-1.4-0.8-2.3-2-2.7-3.6c-0.4-2-0.5-3.9,0.2-5.8
                            c0.9-2.4,2.6-3.7,5.1-4.1c1.4-0.2,2.9-0.1,4.2,0.4c2.3,0.9,3.5,2.7,3.9,5c0.2,0.9,0.1,1.9,0.2,2.9C44.2,40.8,40.9,40.8,37.5,40.8z
                             M43.8,38.4c0.1-1.5-1.2-2.8-2.9-2.9c-2.1-0.1-3.1,1.4-3.2,2.9C39.7,38.4,41.7,38.4,43.8,38.4z"/>
                        <path fill="#FAFAFA" d="M44.5,30.9c-2.7,0-5.4,0-8.2,0c0-0.6,0-1.2,0-1.9c2.7,0,5.4,0,8.2,0C44.5,29.6,44.5,30.2,44.5,30.9z"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hexagon5_contact">
        <div id="skype_icon">
            <button class="nonebutton" onclick="skypeFunction()">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <g id="hexagon">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#009FE3" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#009FE3" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#009FE3" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="skype-icon">
                    <g>
                        <path fill="#FAFAFA" d="M44.3,40.8c0.2-0.8,0.3-1.7,0.3-2.5c0-6.5-5.3-11.8-11.8-11.8c-0.7,0-1.4,0.1-2,0.2
                            c-1.1-0.7-2.3-1.1-3.6-1.1c-3.8,0-6.9,3.1-6.9,6.9c0,1.3,0.3,2.4,0.9,3.5C21,36.6,21,37.4,21,38.2C21,44.8,26.3,50,32.8,50
                            c0.7,0,1.5-0.1,2.2-0.2c1,0.5,2.1,0.8,3.2,0.8c3.8,0,6.9-3.1,6.9-6.9C45,42.7,44.8,41.7,44.3,40.8"/>
                        <path fill="#009FE3" d="M29.2,30.5L29.2,30.5c-1,0.4-1.8,0.9-2.3,1.6c-0.5,0.7-0.8,1.5-0.8,2.4c0,0.9,0.3,1.7,0.8,2.4
                            c0.5,0.6,1.2,1.1,2,1.5c0.8,0.4,1.9,0.7,3.1,0.9c0.9,0.2,1.6,0.4,2.2,0.5c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.3,0.7c0.3,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.5,1.1
                            c0,0.6-0.3,1.1-0.9,1.5c-0.6,0.4-1.4,0.6-2.4,0.6c-0.7,0-1.3-0.1-1.7-0.3c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.5-1-0.8c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.7-0.7-1.2
                            c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.7-1c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-1-0.4c-0.5,0-0.9,0.2-1.2,0.5c-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.7-0.5,1.1c0,0.7,0.3,1.4,0.8,2.1
                            c0.5,0.7,1.2,1.3,1.9,1.7c1.1,0.6,2.5,0.9,4.2,0.9c1.4,0,2.7-0.2,3.7-0.6c1-0.4,1.9-1,2.4-1.8c0.5-0.8,0.8-1.7,0.8-2.6
                            c0-0.8-0.2-1.5-0.5-2.1c-0.3-0.6-0.8-1-1.3-1.4c-0.6-0.4-1.2-0.7-2-0.9c-0.8-0.2-1.7-0.5-2.6-0.7c-0.8-0.2-1.3-0.3-1.6-0.4
                            c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.4c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.7c0-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.7-1.1c0.5-0.3,1.2-0.5,2-0.5
                            c0.9,0,1.6,0.2,2,0.5c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.8,1.1,1.3c0.3,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.9c0.2,0.2,0.6,0.3,1,0.3c0.5,0,0.9-0.2,1.2-0.5
                            c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.5-1.1c0-0.4-0.1-0.9-0.4-1.3c-0.2-0.5-0.6-0.9-1.1-1.3c-0.5-0.4-1.2-0.7-2-1c-0.8-0.2-1.7-0.4-2.8-0.4
                            C31.4,29.9,30.2,30.1,29.2,30.5z"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg></button>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hexagon6_contact">
        <div id="email_icon">
            <button class="nonebutton" onclick="emailFunction()">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <g id="hexagon">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#0072C6" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#0072C6" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#0072C6" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="outlook-icon">
                    <g id="hexagon">
                        <g>
                            <rect x="0" y="18.8" fill="#0072C6" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                            <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" fill="#0072C6" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                            <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" fill="#0072C6" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="outlook-icon">
                        <g>
                            <path id="path3" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" fill="#FAFAFA" d="M35.6,30.4v4.9l1.7,1.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.2,0l7.4-5
                                c0-0.6-0.5-1-0.9-1H35.6z"/>
                            <path id="path5" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" fill="#FAFAFA" d="M35.6,37.1l1.6,1.1c0.2,0.2,0.5,0,0.5,0
                                c-0.3,0.2,7.2-4.8,7.2-4.8v9c0,1-0.6,1.4-1.3,1.4h-7.9L35.6,37.1L35.6,37.1z"/>
                            <g id="g23" transform="matrix(3.9178712,0,0,3.9178712,-13.481395,-41.384474)">
                                <path id="path25" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" fill="#FAFAFA" d="M10.5,19.5c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2
                                    c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5c0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5
                                    c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5C10.7,19.5,10.6,19.5,10.5,19.5z"/>
                                <path id="path27" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" fill="#FAFAFA" d="M8.6,17.7v4.9l3.7,0.8V17L8.6,17.7z M11.1,20.9
                                    c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.3c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.8c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.6-0.3
                                    c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.8C11.3,20.5,11.2,20.7,11.1,20.9z"/>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg></button>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hexagon7_contact">
        <div id="steam_icon">
            <svg style="width: 65px; height: 75px;">
                <a xlink:href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198137238833/" target="_blank">
                <g id="hexagon">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0" y="18.8" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -16.3026 46.9124)" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                        <rect x="0.1" y="18.7" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 16.3101 84.4166)" width="64.9" height="37.6"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="steam-icon">
                    <g>
                        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M45.8,28.3c-2.9,0-5.2,2.3-5.2,5.2c0,0,0,0,0,0.1l-3.4,4.9c-0.5,0-1.1,0.1-1.6,0.3
                            c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3l-15.1-6.3c-0.3-1.2-1.1-2.2-2.3-2.7c-1.9-0.8-4.2,0.1-5,2c-0.8,1.9,0.1,4.2,2,5c0.9,0.4,2,0.4,2.9,0
                            c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3l15.2,6.3c0.3,1.2,1.1,2.2,2.2,2.7c1.9,0.8,4.2-0.1,5-2.1c0.2-0.5,0.3-1,0.3-1.6l4.8-3.4c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0
                            c2.9,0,5.2-2.3,5.2-5.2C51,30.7,48.7,28.3,45.8,28.3z M17,31.7c-1.1-0.5-2.4,0.1-2.8,1.2c-0.5,1.1,0.1,2.4,1.2,2.8l1.7,0.7
                            c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.2c-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1-0.2c-1.1-0.5-1.8-1.6-1.8-2.7c0-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.1c0.6-1.5,2.3-2.2,3.8-1.6
                            c0.7,0.3,1.2,0.8,1.5,1.5L17,31.7z M39.8,43.4c-0.6,1.5-2.3,2.2-3.8,1.6c-0.7-0.3-1.2-0.8-1.5-1.4l1.7,0.7
                            c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.8,0.2c0.8,0,1.7-0.5,2-1.3c0.5-1.1-0.1-2.4-1.2-2.8L36,39.5c0.7-0.3,1.4-0.3,2.2,0c0.7,0.3,1.3,0.9,1.6,1.6
                            C40.1,41.9,40.1,42.7,39.8,43.4z M45.8,37c-1.9,0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5c0-1.9,1.6-3.5,3.5-3.5c1.9,0,3.5,1.6,3.5,3.5
                            C49.2,35.4,47.7,37,45.8,37z"/>
                        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M45.8,30.9c-1.4,0-2.6,1.2-2.6,2.6c0,1.4,1.2,2.6,2.6,2.6c1.4,0,2.6-1.2,2.6-2.6
                            C48.4,32.1,47.2,30.9,45.8,30.9z"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<footer>
    <div id="copyright">
        <p>&copy; Copyright by Mike Kaufmann - 2015. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        $emailbody = 'Name: '.$_POST['name']."\n"
        .'Email: '.$_POST['email']."\n"
        .'Nachricht: '.$_POST['message'];
        mail('kaufmann.mike@live.de', 'Mike Kaufmann Homepage - Contact_Message', $emailbody);
        header('location: thanks_message_sended.html');
    }

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["filea"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["filea"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "This file is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "This file is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }

    // FILE UPLOAD from Magic Book
        // request variables
    $from=$_REQUEST["from"];
    $emaila=$_REQUEST["emaila"];
    $filea=$_REQUEST["filea"];

    if ($filea)
    {
    function mail_attachment ($from , $to, $subject, $message, $attachment){
        $fileatt = $attachment; // Path to the file
        $fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type
        $start= strrpos($attachment, '/') == -1 ? strrpos($attachment, '//') : strrpos($attachment, '/')+1;
        $fileatt_name = substr($attachment, $start, strlen($attachment)); // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

        $email_from = $from; // Who the email is from
        $subject = "New Attachment Message";
        $email_subject =  $subject; // The Subject of the email
        $email_txt = $message; // Message that the email has in it

        $email_to = $to; // Who the email is to

        $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

        $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
        $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
        fclose($file);
        $msg_txt="\n\n You have recieved a new attachment message from $from";
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        $email_txt .= $msg_txt;
        $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                    "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
        $email_txt . "\n\n";
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                      " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                      //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                      //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                     $data . "\n\n" .
                      "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

        $ok = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

        if($ok)
        {
        echo "File Sent Successfully.";
        unlink($attachment); // delete a file after attachment sent.
        }
        else
        {
            die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
        }
        }

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filea"]["tmp_name"],'temp/'.basename($_FILES['filea']['name']));
        mail_attachment("$from", "youremailaddress@gmail.com", "subject", "message", ("temp/".$_FILES["filea"]["name"]));
        }

        // Magic Book End
            if ($filea)
            {
            function mail_attachment ($from , $to, $subject, $message, $attachment){
                $fileatt = $attachment; // Path to the file
                $fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type
                $start= strrpos($attachment, '/') == -1 ? strrpos($attachment, '//') : strrpos($attachment, '/')+1;
                $fileatt_name = substr($attachment, $start, strlen($attachment)); // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
            }
            }

            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                echo "Sorry, file already exists. Please rename your file, and upload it again.";
                $uploadOk = 0;

            if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 3000000) {
            echo "I am sorry, but your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
            }

            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "svg" && $imageFileType != "ico" 
            && $imageFileType != "css" && $imageFileType != "html" && $imageFileType != "ai"
            && $imageFileType != "psd" && $imageFileType != "aep" && $imageFileType != "mp4" 
            && $imageFileType != "mp3" && $imageFileType != "prproj" && $imageFileType != "avi") {
            echo "Sorry, this file type is not allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
            }

            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name, $message)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            }

            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
             $emailErr = "Email is required";
            } else {
             $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
             // check if e-mail address is well-formed
             if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
               $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
             }
           }
            }
 ?>
```

Comment: The very first thing I can see is that when user hit submit, it will be redirected to `header('location: thanks_message_sended.html');` and code below this `header location` is just sit there and will do nothing